# Set `scheduledend` on Appointment to null with Javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing Javascript on an Appointment form and need to clear `scheduledend`  DateTime field.

I've tried the obvious way, but it does not work.

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('scheduledstart').setValue(null);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('scheduledend').setValue(null); // Both do nothing
```

How do I make the DateTime field blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
I've just tested on appointment form 'onLoad'

```
crmForm.all.scheduledend.DataValue = ''
```

Comment: But I _can_ clear `subject` this way and it's Application Required too. If not by `setValue(null)`, but there must be other way to wipe `scheduledend`.

Comment: Hey. Try with: crmForm.all.scheduledend.DataValue = ''
I just tested on form onLoad

Comment: crmForm is deprecated in newer versions of CRM, 2013, 2015, 2016 does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You are right you can clear the value -

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('scheduledend').setValue();
```

Should work.

Comment: Turns out it works for other DateTime fields, but _not_ for `scheduledstart` and `scheduledend` on Appointment (and maybe other Activities).

Comment: No errors and no reaction. After your comment I tried `setValue()` in `onChange` function. I it worked in there, but my goal is to make it work `onLoad`. Can you, please, tested onLoad?

Comment: Works on page load here (sorry!). You sure there isn't any other code running that sets the value immediately afterwards?